# Why are processes in Windows 8 32 bit?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, 32-bit

Why are some processes in Windows 8 32-bit? For example: I have the 64 bit version of iTunes, but it is a 32 bit process(in Task Manager). Why is this so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It costs less to do nothing than it does to do something.

Before there was 64-bit there was 32-bit.  And 32-bit applications continue to work in 64-bit Windows. Therefore, a company looks at their product and says "hmm.. does it work?  Yes?  Then don't do anything".

Comment: Yes, but I have a question: if you downloaded the 64 bit version of something, why doesn't run in 64-bit mode?

Comment: It should.  So either you downloaded the 32bit version unknowingly.. or the download was mislabeled.  Perhaps the program is just "64bit compatible" and not really 64 bit.  I don't know the answer.

Comment: A lot of other apps do this(e.g: Firefox, Sunbird, QuickTime, Notepad++, Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop, etc.). But Blender does run 64-bit mode!?!?

Comment: I dont know about most of those apps.. but Microsoft has never released a 64 bit version of Visual Studio.

Comment: That seems odd.

Comment: It's simply economics and the old adage of "why fix something that works". There is no advantage to 64-bit for iTunes. They don't need more memory and processing doesn't justify it.

Comment: I don't know why.  Most apps gain nothing by the conversion to 64 bit.  If your app needs to consume more that 3GB of memory at any one time you might consider the port to 64, but otherwise there's very little reason to put in that kind of effort.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Dan-o, 64 bit also gains some computational speed, not just memory access.  For applications that are properly written in the first place, the only effort it takes to port them to 64 bit is recompiling them with a 64 bit compiler.  Proprietary software vendors however, are notorious for writing bad code, and being too lazy to even bother recompiling, despite the fact that microsoft's SDK has easily supported non i386 architectures for well over 15 years.

Comment: @psusi, 64-bit can also lose computational speed. In fact I'm pretty sure I've seen it lose speed no less often than gaining speed. It really depends on the computation.

Comment: I believe the difference between the x86 and x64 versions of the iTunes installer is that the x86 installer has x86 drivers and the x64 version has x64 drivers. The actual application is x86.

Comment: @Mehrdad, the usual penalty of 64 bit is slightly larger memory footprint, with better computational speed.  This is why google and others have been pushing lately for a hybrid ABI that is 64 bit but with only 32 bit pointers, so you get the best of both worlds.  The only time you will see a loss of computational speed with 64 bit is if you are doing a LOT of pointer manipulation and the 64 bit pointers don't fit in the L1 cache.

Comment: @psusi: That's not quite true -- you don't need to be doing *pointer* manipulation specifically, just 64-bit arithmetic in general. Which isn't that obscure if you think about it, because every `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` that you store anywhere is 64 bits instead of 32. In practice I've run across quite a few situations in which the 32-bit version of some piece of code is faster because of that.

Comment: This is getting to out of hand

Comment: @Mehrdad, ptrdiff_t falls under pointer manipulation.  size_t is usually 64 bit these days even on 32 bit architectures ( or you couldn't handle files > 4GB ), so manipulating it is faster in 64 bit mode, and you have a lot more registers to hold temporary values, contributing more speed.

Comment: @psusi: I don't know of any compiler whose `size_t` is 64-bit in 32-bit code.

Comment: @Mehrdad, sorry, you're right.. I was thinking off_t... size_t is also used for pointer manipulation.

Comment: @psusi: Just because some piece of code uses `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` does not automatically mean that code is doing "pointer manipulation"... that term has a specific, well-understood meaning, and it's not a catch-all phrase. File handles, for example, are not "pointers", but they are represented using `size_t` (or `intptr_t` or similar). If you call that pointer manipulation, then *any* piece of code which ever reads/writes memory is doing some form of "pointer manipulation", which makes the term meaningless!

Comment: @Mehrdad, no, file handles on unix systems are ints, and on windows are HANDLE type, which iirc, is just an alias for int.  size_t and ptrdiff_t exist explicitly for the purpose of defining the size and relative position of objects in memory, thus are intrinsically tied to pointer size.

Comment: take this to Chat people.  This is out of hand and way off topic.

Answer (score 7):

Because you in fact, do *not* have a 64 bit version of iTunes.  There may not *be* a 64 bit version of iTunes.  Proprietary software often does not bother porting their apps to 64 bit because the 32 bit version works well enough.